# httpx parsing error when plus sign appears

Tags: python, parsing, httpx

I'm sending a get request with the following data in order to check the banking status of a payment QR Code in Brazil

```
url = 'https://<bankAPI>/qrcode?qrcode='
data = '00020101021126360014br.gov.bcb.pix0114+55489962650955204000053039865802BR5925TEREZINHA APARECIDA DEL S6008BRASILIA62070503***63040833'
```

if I put this data into a get request like this
response = httpx.get(url+data) and I print the response.url I get

```
https://<bankAPI>/qrcode?qrcode='00020101021126360014br.gov.bcb.pix0114+55489962650955204000053039865802BR5925TEREZINHA%20APARECIDA%20DEL%20S6008BRASILIA62070503***63040833
```

as you can see the plus sign + is not being encoded and I'm forced to use the parsing library before passing the data to httpx
I thought the encoding was handled directly by httpx, is there anything I'm doing wrong?

I tried requests library and it's the same...so now I'm using the Quote function to parse the data but I think HTTX should handle it directly.

Comment: It's your job to provide a properly quoted/escaped url.  The module can't do it for you.

Comment: I was under the impression that HTTX would do it. for instance if I pass data with spaces then it's ok, HTTX takes it correctly adding %20 but then with other cases it's not. So should I always URL ENCODE the data I'm passing to HTTX and assume HTTX does not do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Short answer

Use the `params=` argument for `httpx.get()` for URL encoding more closely aligned with what you seem to expect it to do:

```
data = { 'qrcode': '00020101021126360014br.gov.bcb.pix0114+55489962650955204000053039865802BR5925TEREZINHA APARECIDA DEL S6008BRASILIA62070503***63040833' }
req = httpx.get('https://<bankAPI>/qrcode', params=data)
```

---

##### Longer explanation

URL parsing and encoding in `HTTPX` is handled in [`httpx/_urlparse.py`](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/master/httpx/_urlparse.py).

The characters that get percent-encoded vary with which part of the URL is being processed. For the query string (the part that you're interested in), this is specifically handled in [`_urlparse.py:265-267`](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/cabd1c095e52e2f67ab63ec17941d3a539d7c877/httpx/_urlparse.py#L265-L267). The `safe` parameter passed to `quote()` is a string of characters which should *not* be percent encoded for the given URL component.

In this instance, `safe` is ultimately set to a string containing the following characters:

```
!$&'()*+,;=:/?[]@
```

Conspicuously this includes the `+` token, meaning HTTPX will *not* encode this by default if you build the URL yourself.

On the flipside, passing your query parameters *properly* using the `params` parameter on the `httpx.get()` method does indeed handle this for you [via calls to](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/master/httpx/_urls.py#L431) [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```
import httpx
req = httpx.get('https://reqres.in/', params={'a': 'b+c+d'})
print(req.url) # Result: 'https://reqres.in/?a=b%2Bc%2Bd'
```

[<sup>Repl.it demo</sup>](https://replit.com/@esqew/OrdinaryUnwillingLoop)

In short - if you're going to pass URL parameters and necessarily need them to be handled as you seem to expect, use the `params=` argument.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer.. I'll definitively have a look at it in detail!